# Working on a robust inventory project with C# and Unity, wondering if this is the correct way to retrieve nested values from this json file

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am trying to get the values from `art` from a json file, this includes the values `sid, artId, token, name, description, width, height`  . The data looks more or less like this:

```
{
"searchId": null,
"listings": [{
    "sid": 0,
    "id": 25,
    "status": 3,
    "art": {
        "sid": 0,
        "artId": 24,
        "token": "a5",
        "name": "Aq",
        "description": "Paint",
        "width": 18.0000,
        "height": 24.0000,
        "artist": {
            "token": null,
            "firstName": "V",
            "lastName": "G",
            "visibleInSearch": false,
            "inventoryVisibleInSearch": false
          }
         ]
    }
```

I am constructing a database list like so: `new Art((int)itemData[0]["listings"]["art"][i]
["sid"]` , `new Art((int)itemData[0]["listings"]["art"][i]
["artId"]` and so on.

Is this the correct way to get the values of `art` ?

Using this method I get the error `InvalidOperationException: Instance of JsonData is not a dictionary`

I just switched the json format, so getting this more "nested" data is new for me.

Thanks!

Comment: The example is not valid json. Are you sure you copied everything?

Comment: This is a shorted version of the json file, I am really new to json and I am using jsonLint to validate this, but cant seem get the correct formatting. Is anything standing out?

Comment: i also edited the question to be more specific about what I am trying to do

Comment: Yes, there are some closing "}" missing... But anyway, assuming you have it right in the original, why don't you model that structure and simply have it deserialized?